# Нужно инвертировать функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, urllib, cv2

есть такая функция на python, как сделать наоборот, не всмысле, что получить ссылку, а получить картинку-тип данных как в переменной resp

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(image_to_process)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, в особенности «картинку-тип данных как в переменной resp» выглядит как бессвязный набор слов. Что конкретно вы хотите получить и при чём тут resp?

Comment: в переменную resp попадает картинка из ссылки, потом я ее передаю в переменную image, а там уже другой тип данных, как конвертировать тип данных который получается в image обратно в тип данных который в resp

Comment: Переменная resp имеет тип http.client.HTTPResponse — какой смысл пытаться сконвертировать в него картинку?

Comment: Ну а resp.read() имеет тип bytes, но опять же само по себе это не несёт никакого смысла, так что вопрос пока что продолжает оставаться непонятным

Comment: Дело в том, что я работаю с deta и мне нужно загрузить в их облако картинку, если загружать resp все нормально, но image он не загружает.

Comment: Разобрался, мне нужен bytes, как image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) конвертировать в bytes?